# How to fix error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_html-2.8.so.0 while installing BOINC?

Tags: 16.04, 17.04, boinc

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit, and I'm trying to get BOINC to run from command line, but when I try to, I get this error:

```
svetlana@svetlana-desktop:~/Downloads$ sudo /home/svetlana/Downloads/BOINC
/run_manager
./boincmgr: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_html-2.8.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also followed this [guide](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Installing_BOINC#Ubuntu), but no help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

BOINC is available in the Ubuntu software repositories; unless you have a very specific, unusual need, you can just use this version. (Downloading and installing the version from the BOINC website can lead to dependency issues like the one you've encountered).

Simply run

```
sudo apt install boinc
```

and you will have a basic installation of the client and the manager.

Other boinc packages (for SETI@Home, Boinc Screensaver, etc) are available; you can see the list  http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=boinc&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS comes with libwxgtk3 only, however you might be able to install what you need from the repositories of Ubuntu 15.10, just be aware that the following is not a recommended way of solving this. Search and download the following packages from http://packages.ubuntu.com for the `wily` release. Best to download them into a separate folder.

```
# Note: if you're not planning development you can skip the dbg and dev packages

libwxbase2.8-0_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libwxbase2.8-dbg_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libwxbase2.8-dev_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libwxgtk2.8-0_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libwxgtk2.8-dbg_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libwxgtk2.8-dev_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
wx2.8-doc_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_all.deb
wx2.8-headers_2.8.12.1+dfsg2-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

After you got them all install them with `dpkg -i <package-name>.deb`. They might trow you an error because of dependencies, then simply install that package mentioned first and redo the step.